# How to change the plot background color generated by plot(effect(...)) in grey with white grid in R？

Tags: r, plot, background-color, effect

My R codes:

```
model0_1 <- lm(average_count ~ green_text  + brand_names, data = data)
eff <- effect("green_text", model0_1)
```

I tried to plot the main effect of green_text:

```
plot(eff,
 x.var = "green_text",
 xlab = "Types of Tweets",
 ylab = "Average Count",
 main = "Types of Tweets on Average Count",
 colors = c("#1A9F12"),
 grid = TRUE
)
```

I tried to change the background of the plot into grey with white grid, so that it looked better. However, I kind of lost ways to achieve it.
I have tried

```
rect(usr[1], usr[3], usr[2], usr[4], col = "lightgrey", border = NA)
```

but my jupyter notebook always returns "Error in rect(usr[1], usr[3], usr[2], usr[4], col = "lightgrey", border = NA): plot.new has not been called yet".

To fix it, I tried

```
plot(eff,
 x.var = "green_text",
 xlab = "Types of Tweets",
 ylab = "Average Count",
 main = "Types of Tweets on Average Count",
 colors = c("#1A9F12"),
 grid = TRUE)

plt.new() 
rect(usr[1], usr[3], usr[2], usr[4], col = "lightgrey", border = NA)
```

but then the plot and the grey background were separated in two.
I also saw a saying: {effects} plot is {lattice} based in r, so setting the `par()` won't have any effect. Does anyone know how to achieve this on the base of `plot(effect(...))`?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets close. These are `lattice` plots, so you'll need to dig into the documentation of `?plot.effect` and the `lattice` package documentation (`?lattice::trellis.par.set`) for fine tuning

```r
library(effects)
lattice::trellis.par.set("panel.background", list(col = "gray"))
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
e1 <- effect("hp", m1)
plot(e1, axes = list(grid = TRUE))
```

The OP suggests

```r
lattice::trellis.par.set(
    reference.line = list(col = "#FFFFFF", lwd=2),
    panel.background=list(col="#F6F6F6"))
```

Comment: With Ben's help, I achieved my goal by the following codes: lattice::trellis.par.set(reference.line = list(col = "#FFFFFF", lwd=2),panel.background=list(col="#F6F6F6"))